# Excel: Look up specific value over an array and then count the number of items in specific column

Tags: excel

This is my first post and am only creating this post after not being able to find my specific issue. I am trying to count specific items in a certain column if that column has a specific heading.

Example: My work has an Excel file that different team members mark once they've completed a specific task. I then have a table on another spreadsheet that updates how many tasks a specific team member has completed. The team members have to make these marks every quarter.

[image]

The above image best illustrates what I mean. I would like the COUNTIFS function to automatically update based on cell A15; IE when i change the date, the counter will update for the corresponding column. Right now, I manually adjust the criteria range for every period. I know there must be a way to tie to cell A15 so when I change the cell value, everything else updates automatically. I just can't figure out how to do it. Hopefully someone can help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the index of the column using `MATCH` and use that to offset the range. For example:

[image]

The formula in my example is `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2:A7, 0, MATCH(A9, A1:C1, 0)-1), "=x")`. For you I would use `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A3:A12, 0, MATCH(A15, A2:E2, 0)-1), "=X")`.

Comment: Does this take into account the team member?

Comment: After some trial and error, I feel like I am half way there. Using the image I posted above in my initial question, I am using this function: =COUNTIFS(INDEX(A3:E12,,MATCH(A15,2:2,0)),"X"). This returns "7" (7 is the number of times X appears in column E). However, if I try to do =COUNTIFS(B3:B12,A18,INDEX(A3:E12,,MATCH(A15,2:2,0)),"X"), I get a #VALUE error. It is bothering me since =COUNTIFS(E3:E12,"X") also returns "7" but seems to work when combining the COUNTIFS with the team member name. Hopefully this helps bring me closer to an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multiple criteria using an array formula, e.g.

```
=SUM(IF(IF(B1:D1=A9,IF(A2:A7=A10,B2:D7))="X",1))
```

Where

```
=SUM(IF(IF([Date Range]=[Date Criteria],IF([Team Member Range]=[Team Member Criteria],[All the Xs]))="X",1))
```

Remember to press **Control+Shift+Enter** when entering an array formula

Comment: Appreciate the help! But unfortunately, this is not working for me (even with the ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Hmm it works perfectly for me - Just making sure you don't have manual calculation on (press f9 to calculate), and you're actually in the text edit part of the cell before pressing control shift enter?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Every time I try to do it, I get the error "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated." Strange.